# Cannot add data if the table does not contain any data

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an issue where I cannot add data to the table `RepresentativeImages` because there is no data in the table. In my method below: Only *if* the table contained data it would go through the first `if` statement and add the data, but *if* there is no data in the table yet, it would just step over the `if` statement. I've never worked with an issue like this, so if anyone could please tell me why it's doing this I would be very greatful!

This is a method from my web service.
Here is my coding and I will show where the specific problem lies.

```
public void UpdateRepresentative(RepresentativeView repView)
{
    using (TruckDb db = new TruckDb())
    {
        Representative rep = (from x in db.Represetatives
                            where x.Id == repView.Id
                            select x).First();
        rep.Id = repView.Id;
        rep.Name = repView.Name;
        rep.Surname = repView.Surname;
        rep.Position = repView.Position;
        rep.CellPhone = repView.CellPhone;
        rep.WorkAddress = repView.WorkAddress;
        rep.Email = repView.Email;
        rep.OfficeLine = repView.OfficeLine;
        rep.Fax = repView.Fax;
        rep.Interest = repView.Interest;
        rep.CustomerId = repView.CustomerId;
        rep.Province = repView.Province;

        //-----THE ISSUE LIES HERE-----
        if (db.RepresentativeImages.Any(x => x.RepresentativeId != rep.Id))
        {
            var repImage = new RepresentativeImages
            {
                Image = repView.Image,
                RepresentativeId = rep.Id
            };
            db.RepresentativeImages.Attach(repImage);
            db.RepresentativeImages.Add(repImage);
        }
        else if (db.RepresentativeImages.Any(x => x.RepresentativeId == rep.Id))
        {
            RepresentativeImages repImage = (from x in db.RepresentativeImages
                                             where x.RepresentativeId == rep.Id
                                             select x).First();
            repImage.Image = repView.Image;
            db.RepresentativeImages.Attach(repImage);
            var entryImage = db.Entry(repImage);
            entryImage.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        db.Represetatives.Attach(rep);
        var entry = db.Entry(rep);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The `if` statement is checking if there is any Id's that matches the `repId`, and if it doesn't match it should step through the `if` statement and actually add a new image to the table.

Now I know the cause of my problem. It's because there is no data in the `RepresentativeImages` table yet, so it cannot find any `Id`'s to match to the `repId`. How Can I still add my image to my table, even if there is no data in my table yet?

Comment: u should exclude the if statement in case `Table.Rows.Count == 0 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `if` makes no sense at all from a business perspective. It should be the else clause of your second `if`.

Your business decision should look like this:

> **If** a picture for this id already exists, use that, **else** create a new one.

So:

```
    if (db.RepresentativeImages.Any(x => x.RepresentativeId == rep.Id))
    {
        RepresentativeImages repImage = (from x in db.RepresentativeImages
                                         where x.RepresentativeId == rep.Id
                                         select x).First();
        repImage.Image = repView.Image;
        db.RepresentativeImages.Attach(repImage);
        var entryImage = db.Entry(repImage);
        entryImage.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
    {
        var repImage = new RepresentativeImages
        {
            Image = repView.Image,
            RepresentativeId = rep.Id
        };
        db.RepresentativeImages.Attach(repImage);
        db.RepresentativeImages.Add(repImage);
    }
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for pointing it out to me man. It works correctly now :)